# WordPress Problem with wp_enqueue_script

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I try to us wp_enqueue_script to load my javascript, here is my code:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script('slider','/wp-content/themes/less/js/slider.js',array('jquery'),'1.0'); ?>
```

It's not working, when I look into the source, it turns to be:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wp/wp-content/themes/less/js/slider.js?ver=2.9.2'></script>
```

?ver=2.9.2 is added to the end automatically, I guess this is the reason, how can I fix it.

Comment: @Zack by adding at the end `?ver=2.9.2` ?

Comment: ?ver=2.9.2 is automatically added to the end

Comment: @c0mrade, I tried to add ?ver=2.9.2, to the link, make it: 

/wp-content/themes/less/js/slider.js?ver=2.9.2

it works, as the result it become:
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wp/wp-content/themes/less/js/slider.js?ver=1.0'></script>

so this is the correct way, right?

Comment: Thanks to c0mrade, I wish you tell me what causes that

Comment: WordPress appears to append the version of WordPress installed. I've also tried this and today's current version of WordPress (?ver=3.3.2) was appended to the uri when my parameters weren't following syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove the version parameter you need an extra filter. This is how I use Google’s jQuery without a query string:

```
<?php
// Use the latest jQuery version from Google
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js', false, false);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

add_filter('script_loader_src', 'toscho_script_loader_filter');

function toscho_script_loader_filter($src)
{
    if ( FALSE === strpos($src, 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/') )
    {
        return $src;
    }
    $new_src = explode('?', $src);

    return $new_src[0];
}
?>
```

You may even use the last filter to add your own query vars.

Usually the query string should not affect your script. I remove it just to increase the probability that the user can use a cached version of this file.

Comment: toscho, how can I adapt your script to an add_action function that takes a custom "jquery include" function? the custom function just does what you did int he first two lines and without the wp_enqueue_script at the end.

Comment: @ilia, sorry, I really don’t understand your question. Maybe you should open a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and show the code you’re working on.

Comment: yeah I had a feeling it wouldn't be very clear but I was hoping to avoid creating a new question because it is in fact a very similar situation and yet different enough that I'm still having trouble with it. Anyway, I created a question for it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256025/how-can-i-remove-version-query-var-from-jquery-include-function-in-wordpress

Answer (score 9):

Wordpress's documentation is poorly documented in this regard.

Change from `false` to `null` in the second last parameter to remove `?ver=2.9.2`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use null as the fourth parameter if you are using Wordpress 3.0.This will effectively remove the version.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script('slider','/wp-content/themes/less/js/slider.js',array('jquery'),null); ?>
```